# How to work with this JSON array?

Tags: php, json

I'm using following code right now:

```
$json = json_decode($content, true);

var_dump($json);

echo $json[0]['article'];
```

var_dump($json);

```
array(36) { 
[0]=> string(53) "{"article":"Milk","==":"RandomString"}" 
[1]=> string(56) "{"article":"Water","==":"RandomString"}"
[2]=> string(68) "{"article":"Beef","amount":3,"==":"RandomString"}" 

[3]=> string(4) "null" [4]=> string(4) "null" [5]=> string(4) "null" [6]=> string(4) "null" [7]=> string(4) "null" [8]=> string(4) "null" [9]=> string(4) "null" [10]=> string(4) "null" [11]=> string(4) "null" [12]=> string(4) "null" [13]=> string(4) "null" [14]=> string(4) "null"
}
```

But it returns:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'article' in json.php on line 17
{
```

(Yes that { at the end is outputted too)

Anybody has a idea how I could get this array properly? And how could I also get the amount if any is set?

Comment: If you look at the var dump, it's a string, not an array. Meaning `$content` was valid json, but it was formatted wrong.

Comment: Can you post the output from `var_dump($content);`?

Comment: It looks like $json[0] is itself another json string. To access it as an object you'd need to json_decode it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each array element is another string of JSON, so you need to run `json_decode()` on each of those. The example below does that and overwrites the original element, so `$json` is fully decoded.

```
foreach($json as $key => $moreJson)
{
    $json[$key] = json_decode($moreJson, true);
}

echo $json[0]['article'];
```

Comment: Well, he's already passing the second parameter for `json_decode()` as `TRUE` -- `$json = json_decode($content, true);`.

Comment: Thanks, missed that :)

Comment: It wouldn't still work. The `json_decode()` inside the `foreach` needs the `TRUE`, too. :)

Comment: Haha you're correct. I should have left the code as it was. Feel free to throw an edit in for stuff like that :)

Comment: Sure, from next time. Not all the people react positively towards code edits, so wanted to make sure :)